# animated marker in openlayers3

Tags: javascript, openlayers

i want to add a marker on may map but i have to add pulsate class my marker like google map
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ryanoc/86Ejf/)

can anyone help me?
this is my code

```
 var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
            //create empty vector
        });
        var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
            geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([42, 28)], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')),
            attribute: {}
        });
        vectorSource.addFeature(iconFeature);
        //var iconStyle = isemri.turnBackDefaultMarkerStyle(data[i].isemriKaynagi.name)

        //add the feature vector to the layer vector, and apply a style to whole layer
        var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: vectorSource,
            //style: iconStyle
        });
        vectorLayer.getSource().getFeatures()[0].setStyle(iconStyle)
        vectorLayer.setProperties({ attributes: {}, type: "marker" });
        map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
```

Answer (score 3):

For a few "markers" a solution can be implement them as overlays and use CSS3 or SVG to animate them. See example: http://acanimal.github.io/thebookofopenlayers3/chapter06_markers_overlays.html

Take into account overlays does not offers a great performance, as you can see in the examples, when many overlays are animated.